# Passing 2d array for print in java

Tags: java, object, multidimensional-array, methods

Hi i am new to java as u can see from the code. what i want it to populate an array in one method and then in second method i want to display that array.

```
public class Rulebase {

    String[][] array()
    {
        String[][] table = new String[3][4];
        table[0][0]="1";
        table[0][1]="person(?x),patientid(?y),hasid(?x,?y)";
        table[0][2]="patient(?x)";
        table[0][3]="1";

        table[1][0]="1";
        table[1][1]="patient(?x),hasbp(?x,high)";
        table[1][2]="hassituation(?x,emergency)";
        table[1][3]="1";

        table[2][0]="1";
        table[2][1]="hassituation(?x,emergency)";
        table[2][2]="calldr(emergency)";
        table[2][3]="1"; 
        return table;

    }
    void showarray(String[][] table)
    {
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++)
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            System.out.println(table[i][j]);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Rulebase rb = new Rulebase();
        rb.array();
        rb.showarray();
        // TODO code application logic here

    }

}
```

advice is required please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`array()` is returning the array but you aren't storing it anywhere and `showarray()` needs `String [][]` but you haven't passed anything.

```
String[][] temp= rb.array();
rb.showarray(temp);
```

btw, in `showarray()`  you are hard coding array dimensions(4x4) when your array is 3x4 use `length` instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.println(table[i][j]);
            }
```